# Timeit module, triple quotes code vs function

Tags: python, performance, time, timeit

I was using `timeit` module for measure some the execution of my code, and while checking different scripts I found this big difference on 'the same script' but defined on different ways.

Code.py
import timeit

```
code = '''
def count():
    for i in range(100):
        pass
'''
   
def count():
    for i in range(100):
        pass

print(timeit.timeit(code))
print(timeit.timeit(count))
```

Output:

```
0.17939981000017724
3.7566073690004487
```

What is really happening under the hood? I mean, in both cases the piece of code is exactly the same, but the time execution difference is huge.

Comment: the source code in the string `code` simply defines a function, it doesn't actually *run* the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the string example, you're only defining the function but not actually calling it, so you're essentially timing the function creation rather than its execution.

You'll need to append a `count()` function call at the end of your `code` string for it to actually run and include in the profiling.

```
code = '''
def count():
    for i in range(100):
        pass
count()
'''
```

But note that technically you're timing both the function declaration and it's execution in the string example, and just the function call in the second example.

This would be a fairer comparison:

```
code = '''
def count():
    for i in range(100):
        pass
'''
   
def count2():
    for i in range(100):
        pass

print(timeit.timeit("count()", setup=code))
print(timeit.timeit(count2))
```

Answer (score 0):

`code` in only a string not a function definition.

```
code = '''
def count():
    for i in range(100):
        pass
'''
```

It does not executing any calculation or iteration. `code`:

```
'\ndef count():\n    for i in range(100):\n        pass\n'
```

but `count` is:

```
<function __main__.count()>
```

Comment: But the variable `code` is just plain text, rigth? I mean, I can't call neither execute the code inside `code` without compile() funtion or something like that, can I?

Comment: ``timeit`` executes code provided as a string. Compare ``timeit.timeit("""print(3)""")``. The problem is precisely that ``code`` is a string *of a* function definition – not its execution.